# Android;use "ContentProvider" to download from web server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to use `ContentProvider` for retrieving(query) data from web server?

Some data that are used in App are stored locally and some others stored in web server,I want to encapsulate retrieving data and also storing data by `ContentProvider`.

Obviously retrieving local data is simple and may be done by `ContentProvider.query()` method.My problem is in about use that method to query from web.Clearly I can start `AsyncTask` to fetch data from web,but result returned from `query` method,before terminating `doInBackground()` of AsyncTask and downloaded data never used.

So how can I return downloaded data to query method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use ContentProvider for retrieving(query) data from
>   web server?

No.

> So how can I return downloaded data to query method?

you can not remove the delay of downloading obviously but you can use for example `loader` and after your data is ready(downloaded) insert it to the database and call

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(your uri, null);
```

or you can use other method like `LocalBroadcastManager`  or `EventBus` for sending messages to your object to query the `ContentProvider` again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just move AsyncTask from content provider to main app and catch the result, like

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Cursor>(){
            @Override
            protected Cursor doInBackground(String... params) {
                return getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(...);
            }
        }.execute("");
```

P.S.
Also I've found interesting words in [Google docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) :
**methods query(), insert(), delete(), update(), and getType()—are called from a pool of threads in the content provider's process, not the UI thread for the process**.

But when I've tried to call network operation inside the query method (without AsyncTask) it simply throw NetworkOperationInMainThread exception.